# Nussinov Parallel

Tags: c, parallel-processing, pthreads, bioinformatics

I am a biologist and I am trying to study computer languages. But, when I was trying to learn about the **lpthread** library, it seems odd as the result was lower than the sequential version.

In fact I am still reading the Tanenbaum book. But my main focus is to learn the basics of the calculations of the secondary structure of RNAs. So I found the explanation to the nussinov algorithm in a book and did indeed implement it. But when I tried to make a parallel version I believe that I might be missing the whole point, as this is my first contact with parallel implementations.

My questions are:

**1. How should I implement a data-parallelism version for this algorithm ?**

**2. Why is my implementation slightly slower than the sequential one?**

The code is available on: https://gist.github.com/drenge/6395472 (each file is a different version parallel/sequential)

Comment: No offense, but concurrent programming is *hard*. If you can get a solid, clean, *single-threaded* version of your program done, you'll probably be a lot better off than jumping straight at a multithreaded approach. There are *many* pitfalls.

Comment: (Gotta love the `while(!feof(stdin));`, though -- it beats `getch()` for portability...)

Comment: none taken, but if you could at least give me some directions to what should I understand or what am I missing in my code, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As I said --  a solid, well-constructed single-threaded program would be the best thing you could achieve initially. Then you could go away and work on something *else* and make simple example programs that use threading, until you're really comfortable with all that and have created measurable improvements in other, simpler algorithms, and read some literature in the meantime. *Then* revisit this project, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are two ways to make a parallel version of an algorithm/program.

1. You study the algorithm and write the serial program. Afterwards, you start profiling the program to see where you can obtain speed gains. Those are the places where parallelism might come in handy (might, not will). I call this method the "desparate man's tool". This method is useful (!), but most of the times, the method beneath can provide better performance gains. This way of doing the optimisation method only takes programming and user experience into account.
2. You take the algorithm and try to figure out an other algorithm that permits parallel handling of the problem. Are there independent calculations or steps in the algorithm, are there parts of the algorithm that can be done before other parts completely finish, ... This could be called "the theoretical approach". Keep in mind that every thread has its overhead, and you don't want the overhead to be bigger than the gain you wish to obtain.

In fact, a combination of both is the best way to go (if parallelism is really necessary): first concentrate on method 2 (optimise the algorithm so that is stays scientifically correct, but can be treated in multi threading). Then look at the critical thread (can be found while profiling) and start optimising that thread.

As Kerrek SB already told: parallel programming is a very complex topic, with lots of possible pitfalls. And at the end of the road, you should ask yourself: is it worth the effort. After all: loosing weeks of study and programming time to gain some minutes is not worth your while.

On the other hand, if your program will run thousands of times, frustrating users due to long waiting times or a lack of responsiveness, than maybe, it could be useful to make a more performant version after all. But again: can't you reach the same goal by optimising a sequential version without the parallel clutter? Lot's of algorithms are of order O(exp(x)) or worse and can be reduced to O(x) or even O(log(x)).

Kind regards,
PB

Comment: Thank you for explaining this! 
I will study harder and make all the steps suggested, as this is highly used by biologists.